# how to make django crispy forms responsive?

Tags: html, css, django

> I understand that the Djago crispy forms makes the forms look good, but how can we make the forms responsive?

```html
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
  <form method="POST" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
   <button type="submit" class="btn-purple fa-pull-right">Sign-In</button>
    <br>
  </form>
```

Comment: add `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'` in your settings.py file.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your codes between block content, because the block is used for overriding specific parts of a template.

```
  {% block content %} 
  
 {% endblock content%}
```